# Sencha Touch 2 Loading Failure in Android

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2

I have Sencha Touch app for android in Eclipse,
When I launch the app on mobile with 4.1.1 its work just fine,
When I launch it on 4.0.4 I'm getting a white blank screen  and the error:

> [Ext.Loader] Failed loading {file name}, please verify that the file
>   exists atsencha-touch-all

for all my js file (view, models and the rest..)

The project build for Android 2.3.3.. 
I can't figure out the problem

Comment: Are you properly requiring the file? What does your app.js file look like

Comment: it is working with emulator and mobile device with android 4.1.1.. so I guess I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added to the top 2 lines of my app.js the rows:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({disableCaching:false});
Ext.Ajax.setDisableCaching(false);
```

and the problem solved!

Comment: You probably want to add `enabled: true` config to the `Ext.Loader` if you're using MVC without `Ext.require`